# Solution of $\vec x^2=1, \vec y^2=1, \vec x\cdot \vec y=-1/2$

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ are two coordinates on two separate $S^3$'s. Concretely, one can parameterize them as
$$\vec x= (\cos\theta, \sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi\cos\eta, \sin\theta\sin\phi\sin\eta)$$
$$\vec y= (\cos\theta', \sin\theta'\cos\phi', \sin\theta'\sin\phi'\cos\eta', \sin\theta'\sin\phi'\sin\eta')$$
I am interested in finding the solutions of
$$\vec x \cdot \vec y= -\frac{1}{2}$$
It can be easily varified that one particular solution is
$$\theta= \theta'\pm \frac{2\pi}{3}, ~~~ \phi=\phi', ~~~ \eta=\eta'$$
Are there more solutions to $\vec x \cdot \vec y= -\frac{1}{2}$ beyond the above special solutions? If so, can we have explicit expressions of the most general solutions?

Comment: Of course! $x$ and $y$ combined have 6 degrees of freedom. Specifying their magnitudes reduces this to 4, and specifying their dot product further reduces this to 3. That is a still a three dimensional manifold (most likely a hypercylinder embeddable in $\Bbb{R}^4$) worth of solutions!

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks. Can we write down the solution explicitly?

Comment: Yes, it is homeomorphic to $S^2\times S^1$ (since if we froze $x$, we get a circle from the intersection of the unit sphere with that cone, but $x$ is free to be any point on the sphere)

Comment: Any two unit vectors that meet at an angle of $2\pi/3$ will do.